# How to pass data in rails from a controller to a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get data into my view from my controller in a rails app.  I can instantiate the model in the view and it works.  But when I try from the controller it fails.  I can't seem to find nor figure out the technique.  Can someone provide an example?  The table is actually a view (on SQL server 2005) but I get the same results with a table.

Controller:

```
class ViewviewerimageController < ApplicationController

   def index

        @Viewviewerimage = Viewviewerimage.last

   end

end
```

Model:

```
class Viewviewerimage < ActiveRecord::Base

     self.table_name = "viewviewerimages"
     self.primary_key = 'ImageID'

end
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>

    <title>Image Data</title>

</head>
<body>

    <%= render template: "layouts/header" %>
    <%= render template: "layouts/sidebar" %>

    <div id="content">

    Table
    <% i = TblImage.first %>
    [obj] = <%= i %><br>
    ID = <%= i.DocumentNbr %><br>
    <br>
    View<br>
    <% the = Viewviewerimage.first %>
    [obj] = <%= the %><br>
    Size = <%= the.Size %><br>

    Fails (prints nothing)
    [obj] = <%= @Viewviewerimage %><br>
    <br>

    </div>

    <%= render template: "layouts/footer" %>

</body>
</html>
```

This is really holding me up so any assistance is appreciated.

Stackoverflow seems to prohibit me from editing my comment so I will post it here.

This is my view app\views\viewviewerimage\index.html.erb.

I tried to reference a member from the @Viewviewerimage and receive  "NoMethodError in Viewviewerimage#index" which seems to match getting nothing.  When I print [obj] = the I get a hex number which makes sense, it is an object.

```
[obj] = #<Viewviewerimage:0x620b3f8 >
```

I get nothing when I print @Viewviewerimage.

```
[obj] =
```

Also . . .

```
 <% the = @Viewviewerimage %>[obj] = <% the %> does the same thing as  [obj] = <% @Viewviewerimage %>
```

The answer is here: [How to access data in rails from a view that was created in the controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655603/how-to-access-data-in-rails-from-a-view-that-was-created-in-the-controller)

I omitted several lines of code and one of them was causing the problem.  I had a render :layout => false before the instance was being created.  Apparently this does not work.  Moving it to the end solved the issue.

Comment: Is your view `/views/Viewviewerimage/index`?

Comment: Have you tried [obj] = <%= @Viewviewerimage.Size %><br>?

Comment: see if this works, 
<% the = @Viewviewerimage %>
    [obj] = <%= the %><br>
    Size = <%= the.Size %><br>

Comment: NoMethodError in Viewviewerimage#index

Comment: What is your view file called, and where is it in your view folder i.e. can you answer nextstep's question?

Comment: Question answered above.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of your biggest problems is naming things. A class called Viewviewerimage (view-viewer-image?) makes no sense. Also pay attention to CamelCasing and naming_your_files correctly.

When I try running your example code it seems to be working, so I guess you might have some confusing filenames here or there. When debugging your objects, you can always use `.inspect` to show them in the view. If you put `<%= @Viewviewerimage.inspect %>` in your view that corresponds to your controller you should see the model.

In your scenario make sure your controller goes into:

`app/controllers/viewviewerimage_controller.rb`

and that you have a route:

`resources :viewviewerimage`

I suggest renaming the lot at least to something like `class ViewViewerImage`, putting it in a file named `view_viewer_image.rb`, same goes for the controller.

Comment: The name make make no sense to you but you are seeing less than 1% of the code and it is the result of coding standards.  When you deal with an enterprise class erp application it is imperative to follow the coding standards, trust me on this one.  When you are dealing with hundreds of objects not every single one of them may "sound good" to you, but following the standards saves time coding so please do not concern yourself with the name.  I renamed the items you suggested and it produced the same results.  I tried inspect and the object is nil.

Comment: That *may* be true (although there are 415 models in our RoR app and we've never got near to seeing any need for breaking RoR naming conventions in favour of a bespoke naming standard), but it seems to make it harder to get help from a community for whom "convention over configuration" is such a strong point. Were these standards driven by database naming convention?

Comment: This company has been in business for a number of years.  There are also a number of apps the company relies on for its business.  It makes no sense to rewrite multiple apps just to rename tables or views to fit ruby's naming conventions.  Also I see no reason to rename things just because someone who will never develop applications with them does not like it.  It matters little if I like it or not, I just need to make it work.