# How to access data in rails from a view that was created in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass an instance variable from the controller to the view.  Not sure what I am doing wrong since the view can create an instance and get data.  I can also get data in the console.  When I inspect the instance instantiated in the controller it is nil.  I can't even pass a string.  Can anyone spot my error?

Controller tries to set Test.  I know its being called because if I delete the line
 "render :layout => false" I can see the effects.

```
class ViewviewerimageController < ApplicationController

   def index

        render :layout => false

        @Test = 'XXX'

   end

end
```

And the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>


    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "ERP" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <title>Image Data</title>


</head>
<body>

    <%= render template: "layouts/header" %>
    <%= render template: "layouts/sidebar" %>


    <div id="content">

        Test = <%= @Test %><br>
        inspect = <%= @Test.inspect %><br>

    </div>

    <%= render template: "layouts/footer" %>

</body>
</html>
```

And what I get back is:

```
Test =
inspect = nil
```

I followed a few different tutorials but it seems they left out something and I can't seem to puzzle it out.  I even deleted the CSS and javascript to see if they are interfering but just as I suspected, it wasn't them.

Comment: the view you have shared is application.html.erb file.?

Comment: That is not how the instance variables should look like. Try `@test` instead

Comment: The view I have shard is index.html.erb.  I tried @test and get the same effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have the instance variable created after the `render` is called.
Try doing this

```
def index
  @Test = 'XXX'
  render layout: false
end
```

Comment: :) its always small things.